# Help with the derivation of a thermodynamic equation. How to evaluate a second partial derivative with different variables held constant?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I'm trying to solve the following excersie:

> (a) Derive the equation $$\left(\frac{\partial C_v}{\partial V}\right)_T=T\left(\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial T^2}\right )_V. \tag{1}$$

So far, I've tried solving the $Tds$ equation
$$Tds = C_VdT+T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right )_VdV \tag{2}$$
$$C_V=T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right )_V \tag{3}$$

From there I'd follow the excersie and evaluate
$$\left(\frac{\partial C_V}{\partial V}\right )_T=T\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial V}\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right )_V\right )_T \tag{4}$$

Can this be solved? How can I evaluate a second partial derivative when two different variables are held constante? Also, how could you differentiate holding $T$ constant when the first partial derivate is with respect to $T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The differential of the entropy can be written as:

$$dS= \Big(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\Big)_Vdt+ \Big(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\Big)_TdV$$

As $dS$ is an exact differential

$$\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial V}\Big(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\Big)_V \Big)_T= \Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial T}\Big(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\Big)_T\Big)_V$$

And by one of MAxwell's relations 
$$\Big(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\Big)_T=\Big(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\Big)_V$$

So
$$\Big(\frac{\partial C_V}{\partial V}\Big)_T=T\Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial V}\Big(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\Big)_V\Big)_V$$

$$\Big(\frac{\partial C_V}{\partial V}\Big)_T=T\Big(\frac{\partial^2 P}{\partial T^2}\Big)_V$$